# Login screen flicker after recent 16.04 update NVIDIA GTX 1070

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, graphics, login-screen

I've read through bunch of similar questions and I had issue of "Out of range" while installing Ubuntu 16.04 a month or 2 back. I resolved that by starting with on-board graphics then installing Nvidia proprietary drivers (Just adding info here to avoid confusion).

Anyways yeaterday I updated bunch of packages (not sure what all, I just said install for everything available), I rebooted computer and after selecting Ubuntu it goes through boot-up process. But at login screen my monitor starts flickering (doesn't show login menu). I've tried `nomodeset` and `GFX_MODE`. I've even tried with on board graphics with same results.

I would like to know what is causing the issue or how can I debug or what other information I can provide.

I'm looking at Xorg.0.log and here are few lines (typing them since I can't copy and paste, please excuse me if I make mistakes)

```
(EE) NVIDIA (0): Failed to initialize the GLX module; please check in
your X log file that the GLX module has been loaded in your X server, 
and that the modle is the NVIDIA GLX module. If you continue to 
encounter problems, please try reinstalling the NVIDIA driver.
```

So I think I'll need to re-install drivers but how?
How do I get console instead of GUI? (nomodeset doesn't work)

[EDIT2] ok so I connected On-board graphics and used `ctrl + alt + f1`, somehow managed to login (I say somehow because gdm3 is continuously trying to invoke again). After that issued `service gdm3 stop`. I'll try to install new nvidia drivers and connect card again to see how that works.

Answer (score 0):

After connecting on-board graphics I used `nomodeset` and then `ctrl + alt + f1` to drop to command line followed by `service gdm3 stop` (until I stop GDM3 console is pretty much useless, GDM keeps retrying and resetting console, maybe next time I'll try ssh)

I couldn't install NVIDIA drivers since card was not plugged in, however I guess that fixed issue. Plugged in my card to try and install drivers instead it just worked.

I don't understand exactly what or how it got fixed but I would very much like to know the reasons and solution if possible.

Keeping question open for proper answer.